# Add text from div to textarea on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to allow users to edit their posts, to do this i'd like them to be able to click a link, once pressed the div their post is in originally would hide and a new div would be visible with the text from the old div inside the textarea - so they can literally edit their old post with ease.

I've tried searching for the past hour and cannot find a solid answer anywhere.

The HTML I have:

```
<div class="post-content">
    <div class="post-inner-content">
        <p>Users comment will go here</p>
    </div><!-- .post-inner-content -->
    <a href="#" class="edit-post">Edit Post</a>
    <div class="edit-post-area">
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div><!-- .edit-post-area -->
</div><!-- .post-content -->
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Put that JS code here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IDs instead of classes and select them that way:

```
<div class="post-content">
    <div id="post-inner-content">
        <p>Users comment will go here</p>
    </div><!-- .post-inner-content -->
    <a href="#" id="edit-post">Edit Post</a>
    <div id="edit-post-area">
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div><!-- .edit-post-area -->
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#edit-post").click(function() {
    //Get the text
    var text = $("#post-inner-content").text()

    //Create a text area selector (container, rather)
    var textarea = $("#edit-post-area");

    //Give the textarea a value
    $("textarea", textarea).val(text);

    //Show it
    textarea.show();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dy92d)

Comment: This will limit him to one "comment" -- why would you say use IDs instead of classes?

Comment: @CaseyFalk: I think tymeJ's answer is correct (and up voted it); but, OP asks "Is there any way to do this also without using the siblings selector".  This is a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Should be pretty simple:

```
$("a.edit-post").click(function() {
    //Get the text
    var text = $(this).prev("div.post-inner-content").text();

    //Create a text area selector (container, rather)
    var textarea = $(this).next("div.edit-post-area");

    //Give the textarea a value
    $("textarea", textarea).val(text);

    //Show it (if hidden)
    //textarea.show();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tudcP/

Comment: Why are you using `textarea.show();`? It isn't necessary, no? Nor do you need to specify `$("textarea", textarea)` again; instead you could just pass your `textarea` variable.

Comment: @CaseyFalk -- I assume it was hidden on load - and the `$("textarea", textarea)` is very necessary - `textarea` is the container holding the actual `textarea` element, that syntax will find the `textarea` inside the container.

Comment: I've tried this with no luck, the text doesn't seem to insert in to the textarea. The textarea is indeed hidden on load.

Comment: Ahh! Certainly. I misread and thought the class was on the textarea itself. My apologies.

Comment: @Nikki Mather: Remove the 'p' from the 'div.post-inner-content p' selctor and try again.

Comment: Also, why not use the `siblings` selector instead of the rather hard-coded `next` and `prev`? They're not future-safe if you ever want to re-order the elements (even if it is minutely faster).

Comment: Thanks. I removed the p from the jQuery but still not working. Is there any way to do this also without using the siblings selector etc, as i may want to move the "edit" link to a sidebar in future.

Comment: @NikkiMather -- There's always a way to do it...use ID's, or custom data-* attributes to differentiate between elements and so on. The code above does work - see the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you can use this:

**js**

```
$(".edit-post").on("click", 
               function(){                      
                   var edit = $(this)
                   .prev()
                   .find("p")
                   .html();//find comment to edit

                    $(this)
                    .next()
                    .find("textarea")
                    .val(edit);//find textarea and insert comments to edit                                        
               });
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4m9F/19/)